# jQuery iterating JSON - a is undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I've seen similar posts about this but I haven't found an example of looping an array of key value pairs in this format:

```
{
"quotes": [
    {
      "author": "Author One",
      "quote": "Quote One"
    },
    {
      "author": "Author Two",
      "quote": "Quote Two"
    },
    {
      "author": "Author Three",
      "quote": "Quote Three"
    }
]
}
```

I'm not sure why this code is not working i.e., when I try to iterate over the JSON data returned from the Ajax call I'm unable to reference the named array in the JSON file like `data.quotes`. How do I loop the quotes array in the data returned from the Ajax call

```
var QUOTE = {
container: '#quote',
url: 'quotes.json',

load: function() {
var _quote = this;
$.ajax({ 
  type:"get", 
  url: this.url, 
  success: function(data){
    $.each(data.quotes, function(i, val) {  
      console.log(i, val);
    });
  }
});
```

This seems like it should work but I get `a is undefined` for the `$.each()` call.

Thanks for any help,

J

Comment: If your ajax call is actually returning the data you've presented, then `data.quotes` would be an array of objects.  So, each `$.each()` call would be iterating through that array and the argument `val` inside the `each()` callback would be an object.  If you're getting an error on the `each()` call, then data.quotes is probably not what you expected it to be.  You should break there in the debugger and inspect what `data` is.

Comment: Are you compressing your code somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be nothing wrong with the code. `val.author` and `val.quote` should contain what you expect.

There is no variable called `a` so where is that error coming from?

My guess is that data is not what you expect. Try `console.log(data);` to see if it right.

Check if it is a string, or an Object. You may need to `data = $.parseJSON(data)` to convert the string to a data structure.

Comment: console.log(data) shows the contents of the quotes.json file but console.log(data.quotes) is undefined.

Comment: Is data a string or an object? I added a suggestion to the answer.

Comment: I had a similar problem, i had to remove [] around json string, to be able to reference it like data.quotes